# Can you volunteer at a library, even if you must shelve books about idol worship?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, avodah-zarah, books-generally

Large university libraries probably hold books about religions which contain idol worship.  (They might also hold books about sexual immorality and [murder](https://ocul-yor.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/permalink/01OCUL_YOR/26r5oc/alma9912969323505162).)

Libraries make books available to the public. If I put a book about idolatry on its correct shelf, perhaps I'm helping to make it available to readers. Those readers, in turn, might then be inspired to start practicing idolatry, or to increase their idolatrous acts.

For the purposes of this question, please assume:  If you volunteer at a certain university library, you'll be required to put idolatrous books in their correct place on the shelf, at least occasionally.

If so, are you allowed to volunteer at such a library?

**Note:**  The halachic information you read on this website is not guaranteed to be correct.  Please consult your own rabbi, for [multiple reasons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Comment: Should you not work for a large book publishing house on the grounds that they occasionally publish books about "religions that contain idol worship"?

Comment: I would say that as the work is cleaning up and shelving books and is agnostic to the content of the books per se it would be okay but as per the usual disclaimer do consult with your LOR

Comment: @unforgettableidSupportsMonica If that's your worry, that's probably far off enough a grama that it wouldn't prohibit the work. That's like saying I can't work in a supermarket because someone might come in and buy the milk that _I shelved_ and use it to make basar v'chalav

Comment: A bigger problem, IMO, would be mar'is ayin. If people see you dealing with idolatrous books, they might believe that A. It's ok to read such books, or B. You're an idolater